# How I can use the containers created by docker desktop in a docker ce installed on WSL2

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

The grace period of docker desktop is up.
I have some containers installed and I would like to use them in a new docker ce installation in WSL2.
The new installation works correctly but I am not able to find the correct location of the containers and volumes present in docker desktop.

Is it possible to reuse the existing containers?
Thank you!

Comment: "The grace period of docker desktop is up" - what does that mean?

Comment: After January 31st, it won't be free anymore under certain conditions. Unfortunatly I am in these conditions :(

Comment: If 5 dollar per month are a problem for your company (which, to not be eligible to use a free plan, has more than 250 employees or makes more than $10 million per year in revenue), you should really check how long it takes you to adapt your workflow to the new structure. That might quickly consume the license fee of some years...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your windows `C:/` unit maps to `/mnt/c/` inside WSL2.

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/wsl/faq

If your volumes are here: `C:/Users/<your-user>/volume` , then you can find them here `/mnt/c/users/<your-user>/volume`

Comment: Thank you Nuno, you are right, but at the end of the day we decided to purchase the docker desktop's licences